# Add data to CoreData entity the first time the app is loaded?

Tags: ios, core-data

There is some data that I need to store in a CoreData entity. Whether I can pre-store data in the CoreData, which is carried over when it's distributed. Or if I need to run something when it loads to check to see if there is anything in the entity, and add these rows to if it there isn't. (This data isn't something a user can change. They're preset data points that will only change when I release a new version).

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create a .plist file. And, at first launch (there are different way to do this: using NSUserDefaults, or checking what's in the CoreData DataBase...), setting the data in that .plist file to your CoreData DataBase...

Answer (score 0):

If they are pre-sets that only change with new versions, you'll need to detect an existing database of the previous version and use migration techniques. When you open the database at startup, your code will check the error code returned and if it's not the current version, re-make the database, updating your pre-set fields and then re-making the user's data (assuming there is some?)

As for storage of the pre-sets themselves, either a plist or hard-coded, although plist is preferred.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

and a great tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration